# Cannot resolve symbol "Data" on graphql query class

Tags: java, android, apollo

When I try to enqueue a query, the IDE (android studio) gives me an error on (the query class) `aniListMediaQuery` .Data. It says: 
"Cannot resolve symbol data" . If I try to build I get the following error: `error: package aniListMediaQuery does not exist.`

I have the following code:

```
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        ApolloClient apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
                .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
                .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        AniListMediaQuery aniListMediaQuery = AniListMediaQuery.builder().build();

        apolloClient.query(aniListMediaQuery).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<aniListMediaQuery.Data>() {
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<aniListMediaQuery.Data> response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {

            }
        });
```

My folder structure for appolo has been setup like this:

```
src > main > graphql > nl.hsleiden.wesley.aniboard > schema.json

src > main > graphql > nl.hsleiden.wesley.aniboard > AniListMediaQuery.graphql
```

and my main files are in:

```
src > main > java > nl.hsleiden.wesley.aniboard >
```

I'm using **apollo-runtime:1.0.0-alpha5**

Could someone help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I used the variable instead of the class in the callback.